# return the numeric value of a indexed variable rather than its name

Tags: bash, echo, for

The following piece of code illustrates my problem
I'm afraid I oversimplified it way too much in the first round.

```
#!/bin/bash
dogLover=1
catLover=2
for ii in dog cat
    do
        petLover=${ii}Lover
        echo (evaluate $petLover)
    done
```

I want the code to return the numeric values 1 and 2 rather than dog and cat.  Presumably this is easy to do, but I can't seem to see how on the web.

What I really need is a bash equivalent of the "eval" command in matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what StephaneChazelas said is correct in that you can use `eval`, as a general practice many people try to stay away from eval.

What you can do for this is to use 'indirect expansion'. It's a bashism that is used when you have a variable that contains the name of another variable. To use it, just prefix the variable with a `!` inside a curly brace.

For example:

```
# var=foobar
# varname=var
# echo "${!varname}"
foobar
```

The downside of this is that it's not POSIX. Meaning it's not guaranteed to be available on all shells. But since the tags on your question included `bash`, this might be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.    I like this, but also like the eval approach by @StephaneChazelas.  I'm curious as to why people stay away from eval?

Comment: In most languages `eval` is considered dirty because there is usually a cleaner way, and it's easy to break/abuse. For example, in this specific case `eval` will run arbitrary code, when all we want is the 'indirect expansion'. In StephaneChazelas' answer you could exploit it by crafting `ii` such that the eval would run a command. By doing indirect expansion the expansion would fail, but it would be safe.

Comment: `${!x}` is `bash` specific, other shells do it differently when they do support something like that, like `zsh` has `${(P)x}` and `ksh93` has namerefs (where `${!x}` is actually the opposite of `bash`'s `${!x}`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, that is explained in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

To dereference, in any Bourne or POSIX shell:

```
dogLover=1
ii=dog
eval "petLover=\${${ii}Lover}"
echo "$petLover"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you are not using the text 'dog' and 'cat' not the variables.

Use

```
for ii in $dog $cat ; do
```

this will expand to

```
for ii in 1 2 ; do
```